# What does the leading ./ in a glob pattern do?

Tags: javascript, gulp, glob

While using glob patterns to find files with gulp.src, I could not see any difference in files found between `./src/**/*.js` and `src/**/*.js` globs. What is the purpose of the `./` if there is any at all?

Comment: a single dot refers the current directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's being explicit about the path beginning from the local directory. It's usually redundant, but for some shells, with certain commands, they may allow it to use different behaviors if the `./` isn't supplied, e.g. with `zsh` and the `cd` command, it will treat `cd ./foo` as "only go to `foo` if it is a subdirectory of the current directory", while `cd foo` will check `CDPATH` for alternate targets.